# Exchanging an integral with a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

I want to show that the two definitions of convolution $$u * \varphi, \quad u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \,\, \mbox{and}\,\, \varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$$ coincide when I consider $\varphi$ as a function and as a distribution.

Let $\psi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then

\begin{align}
(u*\varphi)*\psi (x)&=\int \psi(y)(u*\varphi)(x-y)\, dy\\
&=\int \psi(y) \langle u, \varphi (x-y-\cdot) \rangle \, dy\\
&=\langle u, \int \varphi(x-\cdot-y) \psi(y)\, dy \rangle\\
&=\langle u, (\varphi * \psi)(x-\cdot) \rangle\\
&=u *(\varphi* \psi)(x).
\end{align}

Therefore the two definitons coincide.

My problem is

> Why can I exchange the integral with $u$ in the third equality?

I would like a good justification. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you have excess to Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis by any chance? He invokes an argument around the "nice" convergence in the topology of Schwartz function of the Riemann sum. I didn't fully read it. Looks messy, but I still wanted to share.

Comment: What two definitions do you have?

Comment: 1- $u * \varphi(x)=\langle u, \varphi (x-\cdot)\rangle$ .   2- $u *\varphi$ is the only distribution such that $(u *\varphi)*\psi= u *(\varphi * \psi) \quad \forall \, \psi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, when we consider $\varphi$ as a distribution.

Comment: So the second definition expands to $((u*\varphi)*\psi)(z) = \langle u(x), \langle \varphi(y), \psi(z-x-y) \rangle \rangle$?

Comment: There is a general Fubini thm for distributions see related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323399/fubini-tonelli-theorem-for-distributions/3323463#comment6850682_3323463